# Espresso CursorMatchers.withRowString() give CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException with Spinners

Tags: android, android-espresso

When writing the instrumented tests for android, My Spinners are using SimpleCursorAdapter and loaded with CursorLoader. When ever I try to select and item in spinner using the code.

```
onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(Cursor.class)), CursorMatchers.withRowString("value","Yes")))
                .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.mySpinner))
                .perform();
```

I am getting the error

```
net.sqlcipher.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 requested, with a size of 2
at net.sqlcipher.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:556)
at net.sqlcipher.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:222)
at net.sqlcipher.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:43)
at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:137)
at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:137)
at android.support.test.espresso.matcher.CursorMatchers$7.apply(CursorMatchers.java:245)
at android.support.test.espresso.matcher.CursorMatchers$CursorMatcher.matchesSafely(CursorMatchers.java:113)
at android.support.test.espresso.matcher.CursorMatchers$CursorMatcher.matchesSafely(CursorMatchers.java:61)
at android.support.test.espresso.matcher.BoundedMatcher.matches(BoundedMatcher.java:73)
at org.hamcrest.core.AllOf.matches(AllOf.java:27)
at org.hamcrest.DiagnosingMatcher.matches(DiagnosingMatcher.java:12)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.AdapterDataLoaderAction.perform(AdapterDataLoaderAction.java:83)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction.java:144)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5459)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

If I am accessing a cursor with 5 columns the error will be,

```
net.sqlcipher.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 requested, with a size of 5
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a hint in your spinner. It seems that the withRowString() method sees the hint as a part of the adapter, even though it isn't and that's why you get the index out of bounds error.

I say this because I had the exact same error and removing the hint fixed it for me.